# Call_back is not functioning like it did before

Tags: rust, fltk

The below code quit working and I don't know what I did to it.  For some reason the call_back does not function.  The print statements do show up but it appears that it is just flowing right thru the call_back.

```
fn wallet_check(main_win: &mut Window, mut s_wallet: StrucWallet) {
    println!("Enter wallet check");
    let mut wall_group = fltk::group::Group::new(50, 90, 500, 300, "");
    wall_group.set_frame(FrameType::FlatBox);
    wall_group.end();
    wall_group.show();
    main_win.add(&wall_group);
    wall_group.redraw();
    wall_group.set_color(Color::by_index(2));

    let wall_name = fltk::input::Input::new(220, 105, 170, 20, "Wallet Name:");
    wall_group.add(&wall_name);
    let mut btn_wall_verify = fltk::button::Button::new(220, 130, 60, 20, "Verify");
    wall_group.add(&btn_wall_verify);
    println!("Just before callback");
    btn_wall_verify.set_callback(move |_| {
        let wall_name_clone = wall_name.clone();
        wallet_verify(s_wallet.clone());
        if s_wallet.StrucWalletName == wall_name_clone.value().to_string() {
            dialog::message(
                500,
                500,
                "This Wallet already exists in the database.  Please select another.",
            );
        }
        wall_group.hide();
    });
}
```

Mo_Al_ if you answer this I really like that you point me to the solution but don't tell me it.  Your videos and help are really appreciated.

Comment: Do print statements inside of your callback print as well?

Comment: no they do not.  also noticed that the screen group is not displaying to select the button.  might be the real cause of my problem.  have to look at that also.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the group was actually hiding behind another window.  Stupid mistake.  thanks to all that helped.